# How to Open Google Maps from Webview click

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I have an app with a webview. The webview links to a mobile webpage where all links work correctly. When I click on a link in this webview, the link opens up in google maps inside the webview. Instead, I want the link to open up the native google maps app. Can anyone tell me how to do this? There is literally nothing online about it. Thank you!

EDIT: Based on Matiash's response. here is the code I have added:

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.MYURL.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `WebViewClient` as the other response indicates, but the correct method to override is [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

Return `true` to indicate that the link has been handled, otherwise `false`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I have created and added the code (see my edit to my original question). Now when I click on a map url, it opens in the default Google Maps app! Only problem is, the url isn't being passed through. Do you have any idea why Uri.parse(url) would pass through a blank url? If not it's okay, you've already helped quite a bit!!

Comment: @user3552105 _the url isn't being passed through_ -- do you mean the map does not open at the correct coordinates?

Comment: @user3552105 Also, a suggestion: if you have a different question, it's better to ask a new one. Editing when you have already accepted an answer may be confusing, since people assume whatever problem you had is already solved :)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, Google maps opens, but doesn't open the location... It simply opens the app. but good call, I'll ask a new one. Thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

i used this code cause ihad maps links and phone numbers links :

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if(url.startsWith("https://maps.google")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
```